# Torch / Lua after installation is not working

Tags: macos, lua, torch

I have followed the following approach in order to install Torch in my machine (Mac).

http://torch.ch/docs/getting-started.html#_

When I am done with the installation, I type:

`$ luarocks install image`
or `$ luarocks lis`

or `$th`

in order to load the `th` or to make updates on the lua packages. It says  "command not found". Do you have any idea how I can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 18):

If you're on a ***Mac*** using the ***bash terminal***, make sure that you've permanently added `/Users/you/torch/install/bin` to your **PATH**.

To do this:

1. Navigate in your terminal to the root directory by running the command:

   ```
   $ cd
   ```
2. Using the text editor of your choice (emacs, vim, etc.) open the **.bash_profile** file for editing. For example:

   ```
   $ emacs .bash_profile
   ```
3. Add the following line to the end of the file (replacing 'you' with your Mac username):

   ```
   PATH=$PATH\:/Users/you/torch/install/bin ; export PATH
   ```
4. Save and exit the text editor
5. Source the changes by running:

   ```
   $ source .bash_profile
   ```
6. Check that your PATH has been updated (look for `/Users/you/torch/install/bin` in the string returned):

   ```
   $ echo $PATH
   ```
7. To make sure it has been changed permanently, completely quit Terminal, open it and run `echo $PATH again`
8. Now try `th` and it should run Torch!

For more help on PATH:
https://kb.iu.edu/d/acar

The Torch installation (at least for me) added the line `. /Users/jb/torch/install/bin/torch-activate` to my **.profile** file, not **.bash_profile**. I tried adding that exact line to .bash_profile but it didn't work, so based on the recommendations here I got rid of the trailing directory and such.

Answer (score 8):

Have you updated your PATH? It should include something like

> /home/user/torch/install/bin

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and following this post deleted and reinstalled  everything. However in the end what helped was adding /home/user/torch/install/bin/ to the PATH variable.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue. I have deleted torch and I have installed it again. I have updated my PATH, and I have ran the `$ luarocks install image` command. After all of these, I was able to ran `$ th` command and in general torch.